# How Can I filter / mask my Df by selecting columns from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df and say I have a list with the column names that I want. What is the best solution to get my desired output? I have not had any success so far. I can extract the data I want and store it and then recreate a new DF but this feels inefficient and I was wondering if there was a more direct way of doing this rather than multi-stepping it.

```
myList = ["02/12/2021", "01/12/2021","30/11/2021"]
```

current Df

```
    Item    02/12/2021  01/12/2021  30/11/2021  29/11/2021  28/11/2021
    x   10  7   2   10  9
    y   2   3   8   1   2
    z   4   4   3   5   1
```

desired output:

```
    Item    02/12/2021  01/12/2021  30/11/2021
    x   10  7   2
    y   2   3   8
    z   4   4   3
```

Comment: it's a bit unusual to have dates as columns. Also, these are `str` values, not actual `Timestamp`s. Nevertheless, in this case you could simply use `df[myList]`, if `myList` is a subset of the columns. If there are values outside the set of columns, then: `df[[k for k in df.columns if k in myList]]`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect